# Waffle SpringBoot error logging - Invalid Authorization header: Negotiate

Tags: java, spring-boot, log4j2, waffle

Our application uses Waffle SpringBoot starter to identify the Active Directory user for user authentication of our application. However, everytime a user logs in, there is an error logged though it does not prevent authentication. This has resulted in ballooning of the log file very soon to 100s of MBs. The error I am getting is as follows

```
05-November 00:46:53 ERROR - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/burganPMS] threw exception 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid Authorization header: Negotiate
    at waffle.util.AuthorizationHeader.getSecurityPackage(AuthorizationHeader.java:94)
    at waffle.spring.NegotiateSecurityFilter.doFilter(NegotiateSecurityFilter.java:104)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)

Nov 05, 2021 10:13:13 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve custom
SEVERE: Exception Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=500, location=/custom_error_page.jsp]
java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid Authorization header: Negotiate
    at waffle.util.AuthorizationHeader.getSecurityPackage(AuthorizationHeader.java:94)
    at waffle.spring.NegotiateSecurityFilter.doFilter(NegotiateSecurityFilter.java:104)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:713)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:464)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:387)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:315)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:394)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:253)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:348)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:173)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:615)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:818)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1627)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I have tried to filter this error from being printed in Log4J2 by using RegexFilter on  `waffle.util.*` but that has also not worked.

I need help to figure

1. If this error is indicative of any wrong configuration?
2. If not, how to turn off printing this error in log files using Log4J2?

Comment: I think the request contains an header parameter "Negotiate" which your auth server is not expecting.

Comment: But this log is being generated by the Waffle JAR that is authenticating. The error is not from the auth server.

Comment: So can you check the Waffle API regarding what it is expecting to contain in the header or if it is possible to configure or override the logs

Comment: Yes, we have checked but unable to find a workable solution or understand what is to be done.